# Aggregation of multiple functions results

Tags: r

I've got list of predictors and data.frame with data. What i would like to do is to use this predictors and combine their results with some aggregation function. How can I do that?

Example data looks as follows:

List of predictors p1 .. pn. (Trees in my case)

Each of predictors returns two columns: 'probability of classification' and '1 - probability of classification' of given row.

I would like to sum 'probabilit of classification' returned by each predictor and compare it to summed '1 - probability of classification'.

Sample data:

```
library('rpart');
size = 10;
samplesize=100;
mydata=data.frame(age=sample(10:40, samplesize, replace=TRUE), weight=rnorm(samplesize, mean = 60, sd = 20), girth=rnorm(samplesize, mean = 60, sd = 20))
mydata=cbind(mydata, dec=((mydata$weight > 40) | (mydata$girth > 60)))
attributes = colnames(mydata)[1:length(colnames(mydata)) - 1] 


model <- list();
for(i in 1:size) {
  attr = sample(1:length(attributes), sample(1:length(attributes)));
  fmla <- as.formula(paste("dec ~ ", paste(attributes[attr], collapse= "+")));
  tree <- rpart(fmla, data=mydata, method="class", control=model$rc);
  model[[i]] <- tree;
}
```

Where model is list of predictors and mydata are actual data. I can now predict with:

```
predict(model[[1]], mydata)
```

**Alternative**

Main thing which I can't achieve in here is to aggregate the results of functions. I can give here even simpler case where I have function:

```
f <- function (x, n) {
  data.frame(first = x + n, second=x * n);
}
```

and would like to get sum of result columns `first` and separately sum of values in `second` column (for each row not globaly) for following calls:

```
f(1:4, 2)
f(1:4, 3)
..
f(1:4, n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution for the alternative:

```
f <- function (x, n) {
  data.frame(first = x + n, second=x * n);
}

n <- 10

l <- lapply(2:n, f, x = 1:4)

### t(sapply(l, colSums))

Reduce('+', l)
```

Comment: Yes, it looks that it will solve also my first problem when I adapt the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry... I didn't noticed this... The result is still summed in wrong dimension. I need at the end 2x4 matrix not 2xn. I have solved that using Reduce function : "Reduce('+', l)"

Comment: OK, did not understood that from the question. Added your solution to the answer. Thanks for the `Reduce` function!